# Vectors on straight line finding value of p

Tags: vector-spaces

**The position vectors of points A and B relative to an origin O are given by**

$$\overrightarrow{OA}=\pmatrix{p\\1\\1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\overrightarrow{OB}=\pmatrix{4\\2\\p},$$

**where $p$ is a constant. 


(i) In the case where OAB is a straight line, state the value of p and find the unit vector in the
direction of OA.[3]**

How to find the value of p(using a mathematical sense), i try to remove constant OB out giving(2) out....

Comment: Hint: The vectors need to be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points $O, A, B$ are collinear iff $OA$ and $OB$ are parallel (linearly dependent).

This is the case iff one is a scalar multiple of the other, and comparing the middle components gives that in this case, $$||\overline{OB}|| = 2 ||\overline{OA}||,$$ and so comparing, e.g., the last entry gives $p = 2$.

A perhaps more geometric solution would be to use the fact that the two vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) are parallel iff their cross product is zero. Computing gives that
$$\overline{OA} \times \overline{OB} = \begin{pmatrix}p - 2 \\ 4 - p^2 \\ 2 p - 4\end{pmatrix},$$
and this is zero iff $p = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Vector OB is some  constant multiple of vector OA.

$$\vec{OA} = \lambda  \vec{OB}$$

After this it's very simple, you have three equations and two unknowns to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem states they're colinear.  Thus there is a cA+B=0.

You know the components of A (p, 1, 1) and B (4, 2, p)

so (cP, c, c) + (4, 2, p) = (0, 0, 0)

then...

a) cP + 4 = 0

b) c+2 = 0

c) c + p = 0

c') c = -p

b') c = -2....    -p = -2...    **p = 2**

=====

Question though.... imagine the problem *didn't* specify they were colinear vectors.  Then I /think/ you couldn't find P, because you'd have to solve for three variables-- the coefficient of A, the coefficient of B, and the coordinate P.  Am I correct?